# I am trying to iterate over this 1D array to get all of the 8 digit numbers but I am not sure how

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-slicing

Here, I am moving a text file to an array and just need to access the specific 8 digit elements from this array.

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\nicho\Downloads')
cik = '0001065280'
cik_nums = []

with open('bd040122.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
            cik_nums.append(line)
               
base_submissions_url = r'https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK' + cik + r'.json'

content = requests.get(base_submissions_url, headers=header)
decoded_content = content.json()

submissions_json_file = open(r'sec_' + cik + r'.json', 'w')
json.dump(decoded_content, submissions_json_file, indent=3)

with open(r'sec_' + cik + r'.json') as sec:
    submissions_mass = json.load(sec)

array = np.array(str(cik_nums).split('\\t'))
array1 = array[1:-1]
array1[:20]
```

Output:

```
       '3724 47TH STREET CT. NW', ' ', 'GIG HARBOR', 'WA', '98335',
       "\\n', '\\n', '0000002303", 'PROSPERA FINANCIAL SERVICES, INC.',
       '00828164', '5429 LBJ FREEWAY', 'SUITE 750', 'DALLAS', 'TX',
       '75240', "\\n', '\\n', '0000002554", 'AEI SECURITIES, INC.',
       '00816750', '1300 WELLS FARGO PLACE', '30 SEVENTH STREET EAST'],
      dtype='<U56')
```

I am looking to have a list looking like this:
['00828164', '00829452', ...]

Comment: Why are you using numpy for this?  Numpy gains you nothing here.  What is the output from?  I don't see a `print`.  Why do you write json and then reload it instead of just using `decpded_content`?  If `decoded_content` is a list of strings, can't you just do `s = [i for i in decoded_content if len(i) == 8]`?

Comment: @TimRoberts decoded_content has nothing to do with what I am trying to accomplish. That is for different code. I am reading in a txt file f and trying to get certain elements. I tried to do numpy to see if I could manipulate it to et anything but I couldn't find anything. The output is the array of my txt file

Comment: Then I have no idea what you're asking.  Perhaps you should eliminate all the code that is irrelevant to the problem.